# Is there any way to redirect to a new page using ajax with response also sent to the new page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect

I want to redirect to a new page after the ajax is `complete/success`. 
That is working fine. But I want to view the response in the new page where I am directing to.

I am not sure if there is any existing way to do it.

```
function directtoedit(object) {

    $('#edit-field-tei-document-und-0-xml').focus();
    $('#toolbar-back').show();

    clickedTitle = object;

    $.ajax({
        url: "tabs/get_old_contents.php",
        data: {
            seltitle: clickedTitle
        },
        type: 'post',
        complete: function(response) {
            location.href = "tabs/test.php"
            console.log('selectHey' + response.responseText); //Want to view response in test.php
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should just redirect to the new page and display the new information there. Don't send the information in the AJAX response. If it is just an alert, then display the alert, set a timer and pause, then just go to the new page.

Comment: You mean I need not change anything in the ajax code . I tried putting an alert in test.php alert('object'+response.responseText);    This gives an  error response not defined

Comment: Have to display the alert BEFORE you switch pages or redirect.

Comment: why not send the data as get? like:
 location.href = "tabs/test.php?response=hi&res2=Yo"

Comment: Yes that is fine . That alert is showing correct data. But I want to view it in test.php by appending it(this response) to an empty div. This function is written in different file and not in  test.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the `response` to local storage and retrieve after redirecting.

```
complete: function(response){
    localStorage.setItem('someName', response);
    //...
}
```

Retrieve the response string from storage after redirecting on page 2:

```
var response = localStorage.getItem('someName');
```

[Browser compatibility for localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Alternatively you can use [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Comment: I tried this . The alert alert('object'+ob); gives object[object Object] 
console.log('checking', ob); does not show anything on console

Comment: @Ara alert does not work with objects. Does this work in your browser: https://jsfiddle.net/myvc22bj/ ???

Comment: I wrote it the way it is written in this jsfiddle link. I get the same alert [object object]

Comment: @Ara Did you save the `response` object in localStorage or `response.responseText`?

Comment: response.responseText solved the problem. Thanks dude :)